# How to Handle When Request Returns None

Tags: python, django

I have a list of `IDs` which corresponds to a set of records (opportunities) in a database. I then pass this list as a parameter in a RESTful `API` request where I am filtering the results (tickets) by `ID`. For each match, the query returns `JSON` data pertaining to the individual record. However, I want to handle when the query does not find a match. I would like to assign some value for this case such as the string "None", because not every `opportunity` has a `ticket`. How can I make sure there exists some value in `presales_tickets` for every `ID` in `opportunity_list`? Could I provide a default value in the request for this case?

views.py

```
    opportunities = cwObj.get_opportunities()

    temp = []
    opportunity_list = []
    cw_presales_engineers = []

    for opportunity in opportunities:
        temp.append(str(opportunity['id']))
        opportunity_list = ','.join(temp)

    presales_tickets = cwObj.get_tickets_by_opportunity(opportunity_list)

    for opportunity in opportunities:
        try:
            if opportunity['id'] == presales_tickets[0]['opportunity']['id']:
                try:
                    for presales_ticket in presales_tickets:
                        cw_engineer = presales_ticket['owner']['name']
                        cw_presales_engineers.append(cw_engineer)
                except:
                    pass
            else:
                cw_engineer = 'None'
                cw_presales_engineers.append(cw_engineer)
        except AttributeError:
            cw_engineer = ''
            cw_presales_engineers.append(cw_engineer)
```

Comment: It is unclear from the code you provided what is going on and what you are trying to accomplish. You might want to provide some model code, so the relationship between tickets and opportunities and engineers is clear. Also, why `if presales_ticket:` at all? Does your list of tickets contain null values? And it is unclear what your outer try: except: is doing, you set the `cw_engineer` var, but you are not doing anything with it.

Comment: @MadWombat I will attempt to clear things up a bit...I have a list which I pass as a parameter in a `GET` request. This request returns records for which values in the list match `IDs` in the database. However, I need to handle when a value in the list does not have a matching record. So, if the `list = [1,2,3,4,5]` returns records of `[a,b,c]` I want to have values for where there was no match...something like `[a,None,b,None,c]'. Basically, I need to keep the pairs together, value from the list and the returned record, even if there is no record. Sorry, I'm not sure how to best explain this.

Comment: I still don't really get it. If you have a model Model1 and you have a list of IDs and you only want records that match the list something like `Model1.objects.filter(id__in=id_list)` should work. If you have a related model Model2 with a foreign key to Model1, something like `Model2.objects.filter(model1__id__in=id_list)` should get you matching records. But you seem to be doing neither, so I am not sure how to help.

Comment: @MadWombat I made some changes to the code snippet. Opportunities and Presales_Tickets are tables related by the primary key "ID" and foreign key "Opportunity ID" respectively

Comment: @MadWombat that is what I am doing, which works fine...but I need to handle when there is no matching record. I want to include a value of "None" in the list `cw_presales_engineers` so as the order of the list is maintained and there are the same number of elements.

Comment: Same number of elements as what? You seem to have a one-to-many link. Or is it a one-to-one?

Comment: Posted a possible answer

Answer (score 0):

So, lets say you have a Ticket model and Opportunity model. Connected via a foreign key.

```
class Opportunity(models.Model):
    ... some fields here ...

class Ticket(models.Model):
    opportunity = models.ForeignKey(Opportunity)
```

and in your view, you get a list of opportunity ids

```
def some_view(request):
    ids = request.GET['ids']
```

It sounds, like what you want is to fetch all the tickets for the supplied opportunities and add some default processing for the opportunities that do not have tickets. If that is the case, why not do something like

```
def some_view(request):
    ids = request.GET['ids']
    tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(opportunity__id__in=ids)
    results = []
    for ticket in tickets:
        result = ... do your thing here ...
        results.append(result)
    # now handle missing opportunities
    good_ids = tickets.values_list('opportunity__id', flat=True).distinct()
    for id in ids:
        if id not in good_ids:
            result = ... do your default processing ...
            results.append(result)
```

Is that what you are trying to do?